# Choosing a second option choice

Tags: application

I am currently applying to MSc pure maths/maths courses. 
One the universities gave me the option to fill out a second choice program. My first choice was pure maths but I put my second choice as applied maths. 
I was wondering, could putting applied maths as my second choice hurt my application because they might think I am not committed enough or 100% sure of doing pure maths?

The university says on the application form that if you are unsuccessful they give you the opportunity to submit a new personal statement for the second choice.

I am considering ringing up the university and telling them to remove my second choice.

What shall I do, does it matter?

Comment: Possibly related, at least tangentially: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34471/how-bad-does-it-look-if-i-asked-the-director-of-graduate-studies-if-i-can-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admissions committees have been in the business of matching grad students with classes and advisors for a long time. To provide the best fit, they have asked students for their specialization preference knowing that while some students are sure of their path (pure, applied, or statistics), others will change their mind with a broader exposure. Listing a second option should **increase** your chances of acceptance, for it gives the admissions committee more options.

While I cannot imagine an admissions committee penalizing students listing a secondary option, they will likely be *displeased* with wishy-washy students calling to change minor application details.

Comment: ok, I think you are right.They asked second for a second choice for a reason. Also I have done both pure and applied at undergraduate.  I suppose that is why they give the opportunity to produce a second personal statement.

Comment: It sounds like you have made the best decision. Hopefully you expressed both your passion for pure math and your honest feelings towards applied math. Universities especially value students who are good communicators.

Comment: By the way, consider creating an account. StackExchange is kind of like a game: you earn points based on the quality of your questions & answers. With more points you gain more powers (access to features like the ability to up-vote good answer).

Comment: yeah I was really honest with applied math. To be honest I dont think that it matters, I was just being paranoid. I mentioned I struggled with some applied maths topics but they have absolutely nothing to do with the applied msc course. I should be ok

Comment: also some maths is better than no maths :)

Comment: In the United States most would say, "Some math is better than no math" ;)